# Specify only first type argument

Tags: typescript

```
function f<T, U>(foo: T, bar: U) {
}

f(1, "x"); // OK, inferes <number, string>
f<number>(1, "x"); // ERROR: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

How can I pass only the first type argument and let TypeScript infer the other?

Comment: Try: f<number, any>(1, "x");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript generics: argument type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687965/typescript-generics-argument-type-inference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't offer partial inference for type parameters - either you define them all explicitly, or you let the compiler handle it.

You can, however, set defaults for type arguments:

```
function f<T, U = any>(foo: T, bar: U) {

}

f<number>(1, "x");
```

Comment: There's an open proposal for partial inference: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242

Answer (score 10):

As @Joe-Clay says, you can set default parameters to make generics optional, but the compiler will [not infer them](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400) the way you want.

A workaround I've used is to split functions up into multiple ones (via [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)), each with one generic parameter.  For example:

```
function f<T,U>(foo:T, bar: U): [T, U] {
  return [foo, bar];
}
```

becomes

```
function curriedF<T>(foo: T) {
    return function <U>(bar: U): [T, U] {
        return [foo, bar]
    }
}
```

Which allows this:

```
var z = curriedF(1)("x"); // [number, string]
var z = curriedF<number>(1)("x"); // also [number, string]
```

Hope that helps; good luck.

---

#### UPDATE 2018-10-19

There is some progress on partial inference (using the `*` sigil to mark "please infer this for me") and it might be present in TypeScript 3.2 or thereabouts.  See [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) for more information.

Comment: First we add types to JavaScript, then we add currying, before you know it we've tricked everyone into using OCaml and all is right with the world :p

Comment: Are you telling me I've been currying without even realizing. Every time I try to read a definition of what it is it goes in one ear and out the other.