# How to apply typescript auto complete types on material-ui makestyles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am working my front-end with material-ui and typescripts,I wonder how to let the classes auto completes on what types or argument I expected it to show , here's my code

```js
export interface StyleProps{
    open : boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme,StyleProps>((theme:Theme) =>createStyles({
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
  },
  loginbg: {
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "block",
    },
  },

  loginsm: {
    display: "block",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "none",
    },
  },
  //.... a lot 
})
export default function Header() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false); 
  const classes = useStyles({open});
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.loginbg}>
            HardoCo-To.Do
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.loginsm}>
            To.Do
          </Typography>
    // a lot ....
```

So what I am asking is that when I typed **"classes."** in my components, I hope to get

**toolbar,loginbg,loginsm** as suggestion , after all , that's why I use typescript . right now it just shows nothing.

Comment: If I remove `<Theme,StyleProps>` from `makeStyles<Theme,StyleProps>`, then the autocomplete works.

Comment: That did work , but the problem is once I removed <Theme,StyleProps>, I can't pass my hooks into makeStyles props , I wonder why is that

Comment: The issue is that TypeScript doesn't allow partial inference of type arguments (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509621/specify-only-first-type-argument), so if you specify the first two, you also need to specify the third (e.g. `makeStyles<Theme,StyleProps,"toolbar" | "loginbg" | "loginsm">`).

Comment: @RyanCogswellI I know what you are saying , but it's clearly not the best way, since I have a lot of components in makestyles , and how do I remove the <Theme,StyleProps> and still can pass my StylesProps into makestyles function , I think their documents didn't give a very clear example on that

Comment: I actually avoid using props in styles. I generally just apply classes conditionally based on props rather than using props directly in the styles.