# Why does T[K] constraint only work when an instance of T is passed to the function

Tags: typescript

```ts
class Test  {
    constructor(public stringprop: string, public numprop: number){}
}

function generic<T, K extends keyof T>(propertyName: K, value: T[K]) {
    return `${propertyName} = ${value}`;
}

function instance<T, K extends keyof T>(instance: T, propertyName: K, value: T[K]) {
    return `${propertyName} = ${value}`;
}

// OK
generic<Test, keyof Test>("numprop", "das")
// Argument of type '"das"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
instance(new Test("das", 1), "numprop", "das")
```

Based on this I have two questions:

1. Why is the first call considered OK but not the second one?
2. Is there a way to type this properly using only the first generic parameter (Test) and no instance passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the generic parameters in your two function *calls* are not equivalent. The equivalent generic call without the instance would be called like:

```
generic<Test, "numprop">("numprop", "das") // error as expected
```

---

When you do this:

```
generic<Test, keyof Test>("numprop", "das")
```

You are saying the generic parameter `K` is `keyof T`, meaning it could be any `keyof T`. When you pass that as the generic type, you are overriding any inference typescript might do. Now `propertyName` is `keyof T`, and not "numprop".

So substituting in the generics, your function becomes:

```
function generic(propertyName: keyof Test, value: Test[keyof Test]) {
    return `${propertyName} = ${value}`;
}
```

Now `"numprop"` satisfies `keyof Test` and `"das"` satisfies `Test[keyof Test]` because `string` is one of the type that some of its properties are (`string | number`).

In the second form:

```
instance(new Test("das", 1), "numprop", 123) // good
```

Typescript infers the specific type of `propertyName` from the argument `"numprop"`. Now `Test["numprop"]` resolves to `string` as you would expect and everything works like it should.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=53&pln=20&pc=53#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu1oG8BQrXAPYDtkAnAV2CVyIAots6AHEgIxAEthpjX8Bzeo3PQBcnJEW48ANLTqpGLdtHwkAtv0EjlKpvCIzoASnTQAvhjMYAZiXzlWBaD3j5d7ADyxJ0ANLR4ADyRnABMYAGt4AE9cSzgAPip1el0kSIA5MBV4EW8vADcwEBJsuABtbwBdI0w6IngkEiJ8aAADABI0JJT0zPgTaABeaA6Cor6WgG5zDCsbOwduZDBbeA8vXwCg-FDoCOjY2ATFpGXgEs9oLqJUjKyc-MLikVhyqvR9Ooam1o6rm97+kMRo9xlMLAB6cHQACCRB4qmcKBi0FSyWgAHIAETBSCY9HQVgwfC4FCQCCsHj4MAseAo3CXMBEXpBIjQZGo2norQ6IjogB0GCcLnEwA8iCQXkxWiSmISUtUMslOIgmIMgucrlFCGQkulAnosqo8rU+sxXgAjAAmADMRkhjlwuGCM3tsPhWXwSNiHIx2Nx+MJShJ0DJFKpNLpDKZWRZbO9kTRXNUPP5GGOp3gVBcAHc4OKjcqzdBzQZdQrTUrcWr0yss-Bc9qkAXcRbS9BjYriza7VCeI7gkA)

Comment: I did think that the difference must mean that the generic parameters are not equivalent. I just didn't know what the equivalent is. Is there a way to type this by only specifying Test as a generic parameter?

Comment: They aren't equivalent though. One is `keyof Test` which is is less specific than the other which is `"numprop" extends keyof Test`. And sadly, generics can either be completely inferred, or all must be explicitly provided. You cannot partially infer generics. [More on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687965/typescript-generics-argument-type-inference)

Answer (score 2):

To answer

> Is there a way to type this properly using only the first generic parameter (Test) and no instance passing?

TypeScript doesn't currently support partial inference of generic type parameters.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for discussion.  Right now you either have to manually specify all the type parameters when you call the function, or you let the compiler infer all the type parameters.  There's no mixing and matching.  (And in case you were wondering, [generic type parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) don't give you this either.)

For now there are a few ways to proceed; the one I prefer is to use a curried function in which the first function has one generic type parameter meant to be specified manually, and it returns another generic function of one generic type parameter meant to be inferred:

```
const hybrid = <T>() => function <K extends keyof T>(propertyName: K, value: T[K]) {
  return `${propertyName} = ${value}`;
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
hybrid<Test>()("numprop", "das"); // error
hybrid<Test>()("numprop", 123); // okay
```

---

The other way to do this is to pass a dummy argument of the type corresponding to the manually specified parameter, which is similar to your `instance` except that you don't actually need a real instance.  You could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to pretend that you're passing one in:

```
instance(null! as Test, "numprop", "das"); // error
instance(null! as Test, "numprop", 123); // okay
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa1gHsB2yATgK7BI6EAUADsQEYgCWw0RjeA5tYTtQFyskhdhwA00Wg2bQ8xALbdeA2XLrxCASjTQAvuj3oAZsTxlG+aB3h51zADyxxAaWjwAHkmsATGAGt4AJ44hnAAfDQ81OpIAQByYHLwAk7iAG5gIMRJcADaTgC6WhhYhPBIxIR40AAGACSoilGEMfGJOtAAvND16ZnwOtUA3Pro6LgEKAAWAXTCXp3QDuFaHaHQxqZI5lV2Lu6eeD7Q-kEhsOGN0XEJ2SnQvVkCsHmFaJjQpeWVNfWXzddtBY9DJZAbDAzTWaMLwORBIZaUABEKkaiPEiK8kERGkG0AA9HjXIQeIR0JC5rDkAjkfJUeIAIwAJgAzDj8YScL4wAFRkYTGYLOxkGBTPAHM5XB5vH5AsEwpQhUgRcBso4JJErq1bmkQaqXkV3p8KlU6g0Nf8te0usC+mCRryCdAAPJOdBWGzCYCUpDiE5yhBUpEoyJo6AYrEadCOgCChA48msKDlMSi0AA5OGIIi09BGDA8DgUJAIIwOHgwAx4NByBIwIQbp5CNBkwFU2mVGpCGmAHToRXK+CUGwAdzgcKRmKzDI06ODvFDmexo37oqHxBAIAAhNBIGPkLPaSH0ZPsbjHeoSX2JgO1xvt7uAz6w3PqKGmayzxyuQEgA)