# Auto calculate generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I wanna achieve this:

```js
declare function func<T, U> (param: U): T

func<SomeType>(value)
```

Above is a function `func` which accept 2 generic type, 1 from input manually, 1 is auto calculate from it's parameters. But it returning error `Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.` which preventing me to make the latter type auto calculated and force me to add more type declare to the function call. How can I achieve this?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuIBcEYDsCeAoMGAOIEAygPYC2IAKvoQLyqZZYAmIAxsDAE6EBm8aNmACWJNBH6CAPJQA0EAKoA+CAAo83GGRQKAlCkpNJbKaQrUCS1bAQhdWIA)

An complex example of my usecase:

```js
function func<T, U, V> (
    param1: (param1: U, param2: V) => T,
    param2: U,
    param3: V,
): T {
    return param1(param2, param3)
}

func<SomeType>(value1, value2, value3)
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuICMAuCMB2BPANNOiATGprvgiAMwnYBQYWADiBAMoD2AtiACpMsBedHVoAzeBgDGYAJbsMEcVIA8PPAFU8ANQB8EABS0IxiIxgAnGJ1QGzl62k2mLV4hC0BKCAL1qjJu1dHHH9jQM5qdxCPNB4IAG9QiHNweHMFcKR9cMIccMoPWgBfWjEJSWUObj5mHX1YCiQ8BqJmgipCoA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript generics: argument type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687965/typescript-generics-argument-type-inference)

Comment: As I understand correctly, this question still dont have solution yet up to TS3.7?

Comment: Yes. Also see [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic) which links to a relevant issue for TypeScript that's still open.

Comment: Thanks. I found correct keywork of this problem is `partial inference`. And looks like  this problem really dont have solution yet since typescript dont supported it.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242

Answer (score -1):

If you don't really care about safety or strict mode, assign types to `any` by default if they're not explicitly specified.

```
function func<T, U = any, V = any> (
    param1: (param1: U, param2: V) => T,
    param2: U,
    param3: V,
): T {
    return param1(param2, param3)
}
```

Example in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuICMAuCMB2BPANNOiATGhvALYBGIAThALwQDMesCIjJ5VtDhA3ACgwWAA4gIAZQD2ZEABVR4hpiwCBAM3gYAxmACWUjBE06APHLwBVeumx4AajZUA+CAAoBELxBExqMMlR3X39AtEs8EIDiCHsASnpXC09vKLIYiJSvNI5YnAE4tDkIAG8siGpweGojNKQ3NMIcHLiBAF81E21TaVkFMWc3VkQkFgIQJvw2Rlaunpl5RTxSShplrhpB4eQxtkntmbUgA)

---

For strict mode and no explicit-any users, you can do as below (with a bit of modification):

```
type First<U> = U extends (arg1: infer T, arg2: any) => any ? T : any;
type Second<U> = U extends (arg1: any, arg2: infer T) => any ? T : any;
type Return<U> = U extends (arg1: any, arg2: any) => infer T ? T : any;


function func<Func extends Function> (
    param1: Func,
    param2: First<Func>,
    param3: Second<Func>,
): Return<Func> {
    return param1(param2, param3)
}
```

To use, you need specify the type of a defined function instead of the returning type.

```
function func2(param1: number, param2: number): number
{
  // do something
}

func<typeof func2>(func2, value1, value2); // automatically calculated
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true&pretty=true#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuICMAuCMB2BPANNOiATGhvALYBGIAThALwQAMesCIAzCeVbQ4wNwAoMFgAOICADEAPABU8AVTwA1AHz0IAClExqMMqghKIOvWWIRlASnrrZQwQDN4GAMZgAlgHsMEZ28JtXX1DUkoaPFN9CwBnMGoPDABzGzQ4hOSIAG9BCDyIanB4al8ogwgAahNg8yEAX0FGkXEpD2o46QV1BgUIEAAPMBAMABMYrV0kw0THGgh5dGokixcAawwvAHcMGzp1NY3tiAB+eYg0A62MIWaJAGUQVx8Rzu6jPsHhsYmlw0vtvCTCwzOayXb7DDrK4nM4XSGHa7CMQSABKRRKrw0vQGQ1G400kz+8KugKWMRWxO24IgINoshh9LhUO2DicLnc3l8-lc0kk7I+uO+fLcnh8eHpDDRYGKGF57NUig0kjaHWFrgVlg0DyeozlblU6k0uXyZUMapwxryZQsSkt1TMnEsFqsaHpOXyBXRpRqSCCZkIkRq7CsggabLc0luXkcfnZhFUmm5AfwbGTrEQwaEQA)

Or of course, you can just stick with the original code and explicitly pass the type for parameters yourself :)

Comment: I really rely on strict type, so this is not work for me.

Comment: If you really rely on strict type, you cannot skip passing the type for `U` and `V`. `any` and `unknown` are the best options you can have to not specify `U` and `V` explicitly. Plus, the typescript playground doesn't show any compilation error.

Comment: Yea, `any` help us to compile successfully, but it makes us pass anything to the function, which make hold point of using typescript useless.

Comment: You can try the hard way like what I updated. But if you have the time to do some research on something unnecessary, just specify the types as you go. I also saw the comment as well as the link for your problem, it's totally redundant because if you don't really care whether they should be specified or not, just mark them with the default type of whatever type you want.